# Adding sbt options to the "Run Scala Console" command in Intellijidea

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt, breeze

Usually I export an environment variable in my shell and then run the sbt console with

```
export SBT_OPTS="-Dcom.github.fommil.netlib.BLAS=com.github.fommil.netlib.NativeRefBLAS"
sbt console
```

The environment variable is required in order to run my code.
I'd like to work within intellijidea but when I click "Run Scala Console" obviously the environment variable is not there and the code fails.

How do I configure the SBT_OPTS in intellijidea?

Answer (score 1):

The solution I found was to do the following

Run -> Edit Configurations -> Scala Console -> VM options

and add

"-Dcom.github.fommil.netlib.BLAS=com.github.fommil.netlib.NativeRefBLAS"